# sql loop and set properties

Tags: mysql, for-loop, row-number

In SQL, I would like to query a list, in order by pageNumber

```
SELECT * FROM `comics` 
WHERE 1
ORDER BY pageNumber ASC
```

Then, I would like to set their pageNumbers based on their index in the query (starting with 1 instead of 0).

Here is my pseudo code for the functionality as desired; where list is the return value of the Select Query above.

```
for(var n:int = 0; n<list.length; n++){
    if(list[n].pageNumber != n+1){
        list[n].pageNumber = n+1
    }
}
```

For example I might have pageNumbers   `5, 17, 23, 24, 18, 7`

The ORDER BY pageNumber ASC will sort this to `5, 7, 17, 18, 23, 24`

I would then like to alter the pageNumbers in order to be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

edit:

@fortheworld MySQL

@cyberkiwi UPDATE

sorry for being unclear.  guess i need to learn more for my questions to be clear :)
thanks for all your help

Comment: If your question is mysql-specific - add the appropriate tag, since different rdbms can provide different solutions.

Comment: Which variant of SQL server are you using? MSSQL, MySQL, Postgre?

Comment: You want an UPDATE query? Or just a SELECT query with the column PageNumber showing 1,2,3..N with no gaps instead of whatever is there at the moment? Please list other columns in `comic`

Comment: @fortheworld: obviously it is mysql ;-) Look at his query ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - True, but I've seen people use the backticks in MSSQL before.

Comment: @fortheworld: uhm, and that would cause a error, i bet. anyway, indeed, specific vendor had to be specified in the tags.

Comment: It most certainly does. They still try it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @I := 0;

  SELECT *,
         @I := @I + 1 AS newPageNumber
    FROM comics
ORDER BY pageNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why peops insist on writing an SQL batch when a single statement will do.

```
SELECT comics.*, @n := @n + 1 AS PageNumber2
FROM (SELECT @n := 0) X CROSS JOIN comics
ORDER BY pageNumber ASC
```